# What is the result of the following integral?

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the following intergration?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^{2}+3y^{2}+xy)e^{-(x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2})}dxdy\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thanks

Comment: Please add some context to your Question.  Why is this interesting or important to you?  Have you tried anything and encountered a difficulty?  What related concepts and/or techniques of integration do you suspect this exercise was intended to learn or appreciate?

Answer (score 2):

Complete the exponent square,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^{2}+3y^{2}+xy)e^{-(x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2})}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}((x+y)^{2}+2y^{2}-xy)e^{-((x+y)^{2}+y^{2})}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(v^{2}+3y^{2}-vy)e^{-(v^{2}+y^{2})}\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\sqrt{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\tfrac{1}{2}+3y^{2})e^{-y^{2}}\mathrm{d}y
\\&=2\pi
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. excellent work